# Exception: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, session

My Project Contain call to SetSession ManyTime SomeTime it's Crashing. Please any one can help me.

Here section code:

```
public Function SetSession(sSessionName As String) As Boolean
Dim intCount As Integer
'Call Refresh
SetSession = False
Dim oSessions As ExtaSessions = Nothing
Dim oSession As ExtraSession = Nothing
moSession = Nothing
oSessions=TryCast(moSystem.Sessions,ExtraSessions)
moSession=TryCast(oSessions.Item(sSessionName),ExtraSession)'=> Crashing in this line
If Information.Err().Number <> 0 Then
For intcount = 1 To  oSessions.Count
oSession = TryCast(oSessions.Item(intCount), ExtraSession)
if oSession.Name = sSessionName then
moSession = oSession
Exit for
End if
NExt
End if
if moSession is Nothing then
Exit Function End If
SetSession = True
End Function
```

In following attachment PrintScreen for Exception

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I fix my problem

before change:

```
Dim oSessions As ExtaSessions = Nothing
Dim oSession As ExtraSession = Nothing
moSession = Nothing
oSessions=TryCast(moSystem.Sessions,ExtraSessions)
moSession=TryCast(oSessions.Item(sSessionName),ExtraSession)
```

after change:

```
Dim oSessions As EXTRA.ExtraSessions
Dim oSession As EXTRA.ExtraSession
moSession = Nothing
moSystem = New Extra.ExtraSystem
Try
oSessions = DirectCast(moSystem.Sessions,EXTRA.ExtraSessions)
moSession = DirectCast(oSessions.Item(sSessionName),EXTRA.ExtraSession)
Catch ex As Exception
Interaction.MsgBox(ex)
End Try
```

I just Init moSystem to Extra.ExtraSystem
and i changed ExtaSessions to EXTRA.ExtraSessions
and DirectCast to trycast and it's work 100%

thx :)